# PDO lastInsertId() not getting value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am not able to get the lastinsertid value using `$db->lastInsertId();` or `$db->lastInsertId('fid');`

```
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();   

$sql = "INSERT INTO ch_files_details (name,extension,size,parent) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());

$stmt->bind_param('ssii', $filename, $extension, $filesize, $parent);  

$stmt->execute();

$fid = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Something missing or wrong there?

I am able to insert into the table but simply cannot get the last inserted id.

```
Table Definition: 
`ch_files_details` (
`fid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` text NOT NULL,
`extension` text NOT NULL,
`size` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`parent` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`fid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

Comment: Put in error checking? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: does your table have an id column?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher there were no errors..

Comment: @m02ph3u5 yes the id column is fid which is auto_increment

Comment: what db are you using? some may not support that feature

Comment: I'm using MySQL database

Comment: It should either return the id or set the SQLSTATE. Any possible side effects? PDO::errorCode is empty after execution/lastInsertId?

Comment: @hakre table definition added in post. I thought PHP MySQL PDO drivers should support simple process like this no?

Comment: I apologize. My mistake was i'm not using PDO like Michael Berkowski mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDO::lastInsertId` does not work here, because *you are not using PDO*. The code you have above is MySQLi code, not PDO.  Use [`mysqli::$insert_id`.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

```
// This is all MySQLi prepared statement code, not PDO!!!
// PDO uses bindParam(), not bind_param(), doesn't have stmt_init(), and doesn't use the 'ssii' type strings for binding
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();   
$sql = "INSERT INTO ch_files_details (name,extension,size,parent) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql) or die($db->error());
$stmt->bind_param('ssii', $filename, $extension, $filesize, $parent);  
$stmt->execute();

// insert_id is a property of the connection MySQLi object
$fid = $db->insert_id;
```

Review [the MySQLi manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) for full details. At some point you ended up in the wrong documentation set.

Comment: Thank you Michael Berkowski. I was confused with mysqli and pdo. No wonder i see PDO uses Commit instead of statement execute.

Comment: PDO uses `execute()` also, but differently. `commit()` is for committing transactions.